# Orgmode clocking export "additional notes"

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

I'm clocking my worktime using orgmode, for the manual see here: https://orgmode.org/manual/Clocking-commands.html

After finishing a task, you have to "clock out". From the manual:

> C-c C-x C-o (org-clock-out)
> Stop the clock (clock-out). This inserts another timestamp at the same location where
> the clock was last started. It also directly computes the resulting time in inserts it
> after the time range as ‘=>HH:MM’. See the variable org-log-note-clock-out for the
> possibility to record an additional note together with the clock-out timestamp.

I can easily create a table of clocked times, https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html

But I can not find a way to include the "additional note", see manual text above, into it. Instead of the Headline I'd like to have the additional note in the clock table.

I even tried org-clock-csv, which exports clocks to csv, see here: https://github.com/atheriel/org-clock-csv
Unfortunately without the additional note!

Currently things look like this:

```
** Meeting I 2023
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2023-07-28 Fr 14:15]--[2023-07-28 Fr 14:35] =>  0:20
- incoming call by boss, being fired
CLOCK: [2023-07-21 Fr 14:04]--[2023-07-21 Fr 18:04] =>  4:00
- writing report
CLOCK: [2023-07-17 Mo 15:57]--[2023-07-17 Mo 16:53] =>  0:56
- write some silly things about meeting
CLOCK: [2023-07-17 Mo 06:25]--[2023-07-17 Mo 12:27] =>  6:02
- Long meeting
:END:
```

Using `org-clock-report`I get:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope subtree :maxlevel 2 :stepskip0 true :block 2023-07 :step day  

Daily report: [2023-07-17 Mo]
| Headline           | Time   |      |
|--------------------+--------+------|
| *Total time*       | *6:58* |      |
|--------------------+--------+------|
| \_  Meeting I 2023 |        | 6:58 |

Daily report: [2023-07-21 Fr]
| Headline           | Time   |      |
|--------------------+--------+------|
| *Total time*       | *4:00* |      |
|--------------------+--------+------|
| \_  Meeting I 2023 |        | 4:00 |

Daily report: [2023-07-28 Fr]
| Headline           | Time   |      |
|--------------------+--------+------|
| *Total time*       | *0:20* |      |
|--------------------+--------+------|
| \_  Meeting I 2023 |        | 0:20 |

#+END:
```

This isn't useful enough. I need the additional notes in this table.

How to export at least the date, the clocked time ("4:00" e.g.) and the note ("writing report") to whatever csv or html or whatever good idea may occur to you, I've got to send it via email.

The result should look like

```
| 23-07-21 | 4:00 | writing report |
```

or

```
| Meeting I 2023 | 23-07-21 | 4:00 | writing report |
```

Thanks!

Comment: To make sure we understand, you want to see something like `| Meeting I 20223 | 4:00 | writing report |` and on the next line (chronologically) `| Meeting I 20223 | 0:20 | incoming call by boss, being fired |` ? Is that right?

Comment: @Trevoke Ah, ok, sorry, I additionaly need the date: `| 23-07-21 | 4:00 | writing report |` would be ok, as well as `| Meeting I 2023 | 23-07-21 | 4:00 | writing report |` .

Comment: Great - please add the example to the body of the question so people don't have to read the comments to understand exactly what you're asking :D

Comment: There is no provision in the standard `org-clocktable-write-default` function to do that. You *could* replace it with your own function (see the `:formatter` header arg in [The Clock Table](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) for some info) but it would mean copying and modifying the above function which is fairly complicated to begin with. You might want to think about reorganizing things instead: if the note is the most important thing, make it a (third-level) heading and have a single clockline in its `LOGBOOK'. That way, you can use the mechanisms that are built-in.

Comment: @Trevoke OK, aspired result added.